# App crashes with low memory only on iPhone 8 iOS 14.4.1

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing a weird error.

I have below method called on tapping a label. The method hides UIDatePicker. This is in UIViewController presented from collection view or table view.

this is in viewDidLoad()

```
self.StartDateLabel.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(self.startDateLabelTapped(_:))))
```

and this is the method called.Tapping the label first time shows the date picker so selector works but tapping again causes the issue. This happens on iPhone 8 only. I have tested on iPhone 11, 8 Plus. This is consistent behaviour.

I have one more such label for another date picker and same happens on that too.

What could be the reason?

```
@objc private func startDateLabelTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if self.startDatePicker.isHidden {
    
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft]) {
    
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
    
    
                    self.startDatePicker.isHidden = false
                }
            } //end of UIView.animate
        } else {
    
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.transitionFlipFromRight]) {
    
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.startDatePicker.isHidden = true //after this memory usage goes high and app crash with below stacktrace.
    
                }
            } //end of UIView.animate
    
        }
    }

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1818499d8 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x195bcfb54 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x181759bbc -[NSOrderedSet initWithSet:copyItems:]
3  UIKitCore                      0x1840e8d30 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18184c01c ___forwarding___
5  CoreFoundation                 0x18184df8c _CF_forwarding_prep_0
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1817ac370 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1817ac330 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1817ab928 _CFXRegistrationPost
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1817ab320 _CFXNotificationPost
10 Foundation                     0x1829e10a0 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
11 Foundation                     0x182a62fa8 -[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore _postDidChangeNotificationExternalChanges:sourceChangeCount:]
12 Foundation                     0x182be31e0 __53-[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore _syncConcurrentlyForced:]_block_invoke_2
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x181481298 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x181482280 _dispatch_client_callout
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1814645b0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1817c95e0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1817c3a88 __CFRunLoopRun
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1817c2ba0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
19 GraphicsServices               0x19852b598 GSEventRunModal
20 UIKitCore                      0x1840b42f4 -[UIApplication _run]
21 UIKitCore                      0x1840b9874 UIApplicationMain
22 Lendable-Test                  0x10524ef38 main + 99 (AppDelegate.swift:99)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x1814a1568 start
```

have checked with print statement after isHidden that the method is called. No app specific code is executed after it and The memory jumps executing some internal code. I can’t catch using breakpoint also as app crash due to memory.

Three screenshots from Instruments. I dont know how to analyse this data

[image]
[image]

memory leak
[image]

I get this stack trace when i pause just before memory tops out. Strangely my app works fine on iPhone 8 simulator but fails only on device !! I save added stack trace. i don't know why collection view related code is executed when i hide a control on another view.

```
#0  0x0000000195bcb498 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x00000001837a5d3c in __68-[NSCollectionLayoutSize _effectiveSizeForContainer:ignoringInsets:]_block_invoke ()
#2  0x00000001837a5c44 in -[NSCollectionLayoutSize _effectiveSizeForContainer:ignoringInsets:] ()
#3  0x00000001837d07a4 in -[_UICollectionLayoutItemSolver layoutFrame] ()
#4  0x00000001837d6ff0 in -[_UICollectionSolutionGroupArrangementItem initWithSolution:] ()
#5  0x00000001837d1764 in -[_UICollectionLayoutItemSolver _solveGroup] ()
#6  0x00000001837d0c64 in -[_UICollectionLayoutItemSolver _solveForContainer:layoutAxis:traitCollection:maxFrameCount:layoutRTL:preferredSizes:solutionRecursionDepth:] ()
#7  0x00000001837d1648 in -[_UICollectionLayoutItemSolver _solveGroup] ()
#8  0x00000001837d0c64 in -[_UICollectionLayoutItemSolver _solveForContainer:layoutAxis:traitCollection:maxFrameCount:layoutRTL:preferredSizes:solutionRecursionDepth:] ()
#9  0x00000001837cf92c in -[_UICollectionLayoutItemSolver solveForContainer:layoutAxis:traitCollection:maxFrameCount:layoutRTL:preferredSizes:] ()
#10 0x00000001837cf89c in -[_UICollectionLayoutItemSolver solveForContainer:layoutAxis:traitCollection:maxFrameCount:layoutRTL:] ()
#11 0x00000001837df388 in -[_UICollectionLayoutSectionFixedSolver _solve] ()
#12 0x00000001837bb1a0 in -[_UICollectionCompositionalLayoutSolver _solveWithSectionLayouts:preferredSizesDict:dataSourceSnapshot:update:] ()
#13 0x00000001837bac24 in -[_UICollectionCompositionalLayoutSolver _solve] ()
#14 0x00000001837b5944 in -[_UICollectionCompositionalLayoutSolver resolveForContainerChange:] ()
#15 0x00000001837acf68 in -[UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout _boundsChangeResolve] ()
#16 0x00000001837aaaec in -[UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout invalidateLayoutWithContext:] ()
#17 0x0000000183832f00 in -[UICollectionView _invalidateLayoutForUpdatedLayoutMarginsIfNeeded] ()
#18 0x0000000183832dc8 in -[UICollectionView layoutMarginsDidChange] ()
#19 0x0000000184592374 in -[UIView _layoutMarginsDidChangeFromOldMargins:] ()
#20 0x0000000184592acc in -[UIView _updateInferredLayoutMarginsFromSuperview:] ()
#21 0x00000001845a50c4 in -[UIView(Geometry) setBounds:] ()
#22 0x0000000184533548 in -[UIScrollView setBounds:] ()
#23 0x0000000183832474 in -[UICollectionView setBounds:] ()
#24 0x00000001845a43b0 in -[UIView(Geometry) _applyISEngineLayoutValuesToBoundsOnly:] ()
#25 0x00000001845a4790 in -[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] ()
#26 0x00000001844c8184 in -[UIScrollView(_UIOldConstraintBasedLayoutSupport) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] ()
#27 0x00000001845a3c8c in __46-[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:]_block_invoke ()
#28 0x00000001817cd1d0 in __NSARRAY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ ()
#29 0x0000000181731478 in -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] ()
#30 0x00000001845a3be8 in -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] ()
#31 0x00000001844d619c in -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _is_layout] ()
#32 0x00000001845ab8ac in -[UIView _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] ()
#33 0x0000000183cff4e8 in -[_UIDatePickerCalendarDateView layoutSubviews] ()
#34 0x00000001845be398 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
#35 0x0000000184ac3df4 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#36 0x0000000184aca398 in CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#37 0x0000000184ad56e8 in CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#38 0x0000000184a20d7c in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) ()
#39 0x0000000184a4af40 in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
#40 0x0000000184a4c1f0 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) ()
#41 0x00000001817c887c in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#42 0x00000001817c2f50 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#43 0x00000001817c3498 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#44 0x00000001817c2ba0 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#45 0x000000019852b598 in GSEventRunModal ()
#46 0x00000001840b42f4 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#47 0x00000001840b9874 in UIApplicationMain ()
#48 0x000000010325aef0 in main at /Users/ashishn/Documents/Developer/XCode Projects/YOVL-Xcode/Source/AppDelegate.swift:99
#49 0x00000001814a1568 in start ()
```

Comment: Generally sender should be set to `UITapGestureRecognizer`, not `Any`, i.e. `func startDateLabelTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)`. I don't know if it can cause such crash though

Comment: I am not using sender object in the method so it may not affect. I have checked with print statement after isHidden  that the method is called. No app specific code is executed after it and The memory jumps executing some internal code. I can’t catch using breakpoint also as app crash due to memory. Added two screenshots from Instruments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are animating a hidden view, and also inserting an async dispatch inside the animation block which changes the hidden state ... this seems wrong to me.

Try this code, which animates the `alpha` property and uses completion block to turn on hidden property when hiding.

```
@objc private func startDateLabelTapped(_ sender: Any) 
{
    if self.startDatePicker.isHidden 
    {
       // un-hide it
       self.startDatePicker.isHidden = false
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft]) 
       {
            // animate alpha to make it visible
            self.startDatePicker.alpha = 1.0
       } completion: { (success: Bool) in
       }
    }
    else
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft]) 
        {
            // animate alpha to make it invisible
            self.startDatePicker.alpha = 0
        } completion: { (success: Bool) in
            // then hide it once animation is complete
            self.startDatePicker.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that this combines the alpha animation with the flip transition ... in other words it will fade in/out during the flip.  If you want these to be discrete, flip then fade in/out, you can achieve this by chaining animations.  Use the `UIView.animation` `completion` block to start the 2nd animation.

Comment: This didn't help. I created a sample project mocking similar scenario ie VC with collection view opening VC with hide/show. Strangely my app works fine on iPhone 8 simulator but fails only on device !! I save added stack trace. i don't know why collection view related code is executed when i hide a control on another view.

Answer (score 0):

Taking hint from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38237833/430690) answer, i embedded the UIDatePicker in UIView and it solved the issue. The issue reported on that thread wasn't same as what i was facing so hope this solution helps similar issues in feature.

I changed method to as below to adde hiding and showing embedding view.

```
@objc private func startDateSelectionLabelTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if self.startDatePicker.isHidden {

            // un-hide it
            self.startDatePicker.isHidden = false
            self.startDatePickerembeddingView.isHidden = false

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.transitionFlipFromTop]) {

                // animate alpha to make it visible
                self.startDatePicker.alpha = 1.0
                
            } //end of UIView.animate
            
        } else {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.transitionFlipFromBottom]) {

                // animate alpha to make it invisible
                self.startDatePicker.alpha = 0
                self.startDatePicker.isHidden = true
                self.startDatePickerembeddingView.isHidden = true

            } //end of UIView.animate

        }
    }
```