# Hiding a UIStackView with nested UISTackviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uistackview

Preface: I took a peek at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064687/4475605) and it didn't solve my problem. Here's a [link to a repo](https://github.com/AdrianBinDC/NestedStackViewAnimation) that shows the error I'm encountering.

I have a `UIViewController` with a vertical `UIStackView` containing nested horizontal `UIStackViews`.

There are two `UIStackViews` that are toggled. If `UIStackViewNumber1` is displayed, `UIStackViewNumber2` is hidden & vice versa. I originally set the view to display both, but it's too crowded.

```
UIStackView
    stackViewThatDoesntMove
    stackViewNumber1
    stackViewNumber2
    stackViewThatDoesntMove
```

Everything works fine with no AutoLayout errors if I don't hide anything. Each of the `UIStackViews` has nested stackViews containing buttons, labels, sliders, etc.  I found the view was too crowded, so I thought I'd set hide one of stackViews and animate the change, as follows:

```
stackViewNumber2.isHidden = true

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33,
               options: [.curveEaseOut],
               animations: {
                self.stackViewNumber1.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.stackViewNumber2.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    },
               completion: nil)
}
```

While I got the desired result in Simulator and on a physical device, the moment I hide one of the UIStackViews, my console fills up with AutoLayout errors.

I took a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064687/4475605) and my problem seemed pretty straightforward. I went with the approach with the least "bookkeeping" and wrapped `stackViewNumber2` in a `UIView`. I end up with the same set of errors I originally had without wrapping `stackViewNumber1` in a `UIView`.

I also read [Apple's documentation on `UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStackView/removeArrangedSubview) and tried playing around with the arrangedSubviews() to set constraints `isActive = false`, as follows:

```
for subview in stackViewNumber2.arrangedSubviews {
    for constraint in subview.constraints {
        constraint.isActive = false
    }
}

stackViewNumber2.updateConstraints()
// then run animation block to update view
```

Is there a more efficient way to hide nested `UIStackViews` without adding an `IBOutlet` for constraint, making sure it's not weak, and doing bookkeeping on whether `isActive` is `true`/`false`?

I think my problem has to do with nested stackViews, but I'm unable to figure out how to address it. Thank you for reading and I welcome suggestions on how to hide a `UIStackView` containing nested `UIStackViews`.

Comment: Does changing hidden property inside the animation block have any different effect. Leaving off layout if needed?

Comment: @agibson007 Thanks for reading. No, it does not have any different effect.

Comment: What do the nested stackviews contain?  Are they sizing themselves with content or are you setting it. Also what's the setup vertical holding horizontal. Just trying to picture it and what might be the hold up. Also instead of deactivating the constraints and instead of hiding the inner stackview what happens if you hide the subviews of those stackview in an animation block.

Comment: One is a horizontal stack of three UIButtons. The others are UISliders with a  UITextField next to them (horizontal as well).

Comment: what about the outside stackview?  I am going to run a test

Comment: I dump everything in the main stackView. Top, Left, and Right are pinned to the edge of the view.

Comment: The UIStackViews at the top of my question are vertical stack views.  The nested stack views are horizontal.

Comment: So does stackViewNumber1 contain another stackview and are both horizontal?  Or do you have a vertical containing a vertical anywhere other than the top level stackview holding 1 vertical being vertical itself?  But so far I have been unable to create any autolayout errors on hiding even with stackview->[stackview->stackview] stackview, stackview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138283/discussion-between-adrian-and-agibson007).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of hiding I think it would be better to remove the stackView itself.

```
myStackView.removeArrangedSubview(playButton)
playButton.removeFromSuperview()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Much cleaner, no errors and no bookkeeping! I'm going to post my final solution below, which is based largely on yours. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I started out wanting to animate hiding one view and unhiding another, but at [Md. Ibrahim Hassan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42850561/4475605), I tried removing the `stackViewNumber1` from the superview and replacing it with `stackViewNumber2`. The end result is much cleaner with minimal bookkeeping, no dragging a bazillion `@IBOutlets` onto the viewController for updating constraints, etc.

The views of `parentStackView` are stored in the stack's `arrangedSubviews()` array in the order they're displayed in `Main.storyboard`.

[image]

In this example, the `arrangedSubviews` array looks like this:

`[topStackView, stackViewNumber1, stackViewNumber2, stopButton]`

I only need to know about `parentStackView`, `stackViewNumber1`, and `stackViewNumber2`, so I dragged 3 outlets to the storyboard, as follows:

```
// StackViews the viewController needs to know about...
@IBOutlet weak var parentStackView: UIStackView!
// note weak is removed from the following 2 stackViews
@IBOutlet var stackViewNumber1: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet var stackViewNumber2: UIStackView!
```

From there, if I want to remove `stackViewNumber2`, the following code removes it:

```
parentStackView.removeArrangedSubview(stackViewNumber2)
// parentStackView.arrangedSubviews() = [topStackView, stackViewNumber1, stopButton]
stackViewNumber2.removeFromSuperview()
parentStackView.insertArrangedSubview(stackViewNumber1, at: 1)
// parentStackView.arrangedSubviews() = [topStackView, stackViewNumber1, stopButton]
```

Now, let's say I want to take out `stackViewNumber1` and replace it with `stackViewNumber2`:

```
parentStackView.removeArrangedSubview(stackViewNumber1)
// parentStackView.arrangedSubviews() = [topStackView, stopButton]
stackViewNumber2.removeFromSuperview()
parentStackView.insertArrangedSubview(stackViewNumber2, at: 1) 
// parentStackView.arrangedSubviews() = [topStackView, stackViewNumber2, stopButton]
```

Recall `stackViewNumber1` and `stackViewNumber2` are not `weak`. The reason is I want to keep them around so I can swap them in and out. I didn't see any adverse impact on memory usage as a result of changing the 2 `UIStackView` outlets to `weak`.

End result: The slew of AutoLayout errors I encountered with my initial approach is gone without a ton of bookkeeping.

**Update:**

With a little more tinkering, I got animation to work, too. Here's the code:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                   delay: 0,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 2.0,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 10.0,
                   options: [.curveEaseOut],
                   animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    },
                   completion: nil)
```